# Inlining behavior when doing unity build (clang)

Tags: c++, cmake, build, clang

To optimize compile time I would like to enable unity build (via CMake) for my embedded system (C++) project. Works great, but as i see it there are some side effects.

One major thing that i observed is that the linked binary has a different size (bigger) than compared to the "normal" build. Looking at the elf file I noticed that there are fewer symbols in the unity built binary compared to the other one. As I see it there is some inlining happening at compile time (initially I thought inlining happens at link time?) and therefore binary size grows, when inlined functions are used multiple times.

Because of the inlining that happens with unity build, the runtime is also slightly shorter.

The concern i have right now is that with growing source code, i get different unity buckets and therefore inlining is not really deterministic.

If my assumption is right, is there a way to counteract to this problem?

Comment: It wouldn't only be inlining.  A unity build makes it easier for the compiler to detect and eliminate dead code (functions that are not called, code that is not reached, etc).   Separate compilation means the compiler cannot always do this, since it can't see across compilation units (e.g.  detect that a function in one compilation unit is not called by another compilation unit in the same program).    While linkers can technically analyse across compilation units, they rarely look for dead code (instead, their purpose is ensuring that used symbols are found and linkages to them established).

Answer (score 0):

First to this aspect

> (initially I thought inlining happens at link time?)

Is compiler and context dependend but in general, compiler and linker are involved here both.

For the general question:

How do you define Unity buckets for you? I guess you mean effectively multiple translation units. If that's the case, nothing is really different to "common" building schemes (each .cpp leads to a single translation unit), so your concerns would have nothing to do with UnityBuild in detail. As a best practice: If you use UnityBuilds, make sure your project/solution is always fine for "common" builds and for UnityBuild likewise. That means for instance: Avoid global using namespaces always (in .cpp and .h), make sure you do not run into static initialization order fiasco (very relevant to your question here), avoid a lot of anonymous namespace usage cases (sad I know...), use a strict include guard scheme and so on...

Comment: Unity buckets are chosen by CMake. `CMAKE_UNITY_BUILD_BATCH_SIZE` is set to `20`. Maybe manually defining buckets would help.

Comment: Ok as I expected. There's no bigger difference to normal translation units creation then. Just basically keep in mind, that the meaning of header and implementation files melt together and the impact of .cpp content to the build has a similar quality to the one of header files now.